# Prayer and accepting God's will in Catholicism

Tags: catholicism, prayer, will-of-god

Is prayer supposed to be the unique means of accepting God's will under Catholic theology? How is a good Catholic supposed to overcome resistance to or confusion about God's will? What do key theologians have to say?

Comment: This is quite a broad question, ∵ God's will is our sanctification (1Thess 4:3: "this is the will of God, your sanctification"). So, are you asking: "How does prayer contribute to our sanctification?"?

Comment: I don't mean to sound ignorant, but I think I don't know enough about how to understand our sanctification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

St. Thomas Aquinas's prayer "Concede mihi, misericors Deus" includes the request "quod a me requiris, ut faciam, tribue ut sciam" ("grant that I may know what you require me to do"). (See, for example, http://www.preces-latinae.org/thesaurus/Varia/Concede.html)

If the greatest theologian of the last millennium felt the need to make that request, it shouldn't be surprising that God's will for the rest of us may also be difficult to discern. We may need to deploy all the tools at our disposal, including our own intelligence, prayer, reading, and consultation with others.

Comment: Thank you. That is fair enough. I suppose it must also be correct that I can never count on discerning God's will in any given instance--that is just how things are...Yes, I do have to use all of the tools at our disposal. I'll confess I don't typically consult with others on this score. That must be on me.